# Heap torsors and dual objects

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, duality

Suppose that $G$ is a group and $P:G\rightarrow G$ is a permutation of $G$. We would now like to apply a forgetful functor to the algebra $(G,\cdot,P,^{-1},e)$.  Whenever $g\in G$, let $gP$ be the permutation of $G$ defined by letting $(gP)(x)=g\cdot(P(x))$. Define
$GP=\{gP\mid g\in G\}$. We would like to forget both the identity of the group $e$ so that the group is a group without basepoint in the same way that an affine space is a vector space without an origin, and we would also like to only remember the coset $GP$ rather than the particular permutation $P$.

**Forgetting the identity of a group:** A heap is a set $G$ along with a ternary operation $L$ that satisfies the following identities:

1. $L(L(p,q,r),s,t)=L(p,L(s,r,q),t)=L(p,q,L(r,s,t))$, and
2. $x=L(x,y,y)=L(y,y,x)$.

A heap should be considered to be an algebraic structure that is like a group but which does not have an identity element. If $(G,L)$ is a heap, and $a\in G$, then $G$ can be made into a group with identity element $a$ by setting $x\cdot y=L(x,a,y)$ and $x^{-1}=L(a,x,a)$. Likewise, if $(G,\cdot,^{-1},e)$ is a group, then one can define a heap operation $L$ on $G$ by letting $L(x,y,z)=xy^{-1}z$.

**Heap with permutation coset**

If $(G,L)$ is a heap, then whenever $P$ is a permutation of $G$, the set of permutations $GP$ only depends on the heap operation $L$ instead of the group operation $\cdot$. We therefore define a heap with permutation coset to be a pair $(G,GP)$ where $P$ is a permutation of $G$.

**Heap torsor**

Suppose that $(G,L)$ is a heap and $X$ is a set. Then a heap action is a mapping $\theta:G\rightarrow\text{Sym}(X)$ such that $\theta(L(i,j,k))=\theta(i)\theta(j)^{-1}\theta(k)$ for all $i,j,k\in G$ (this is not the most general notion of what could justifiably be called a heap action as mentioned in the comments).

Heap actions are closely related to group actions. Suppose that $G$ is a group and not just a heap. A function $\theta:G\rightarrow\text{Sym}(X)$ is a heap action if and only if there exists a permutation $P$ of $X$ and a group action of $G$ on $X$ such that $\theta(g)(x)=g\cdot P(x)$ whenever $g\in G,x\in X$.

A torsor is a group action of $G$ on $X$ such that whenever $x,y\in X$, there is a unique $g\in G$ with $g\cdot x=y$. A heap torsor is a heap action $\theta$ of $G$ on $X$ such that if $x,y\in X$, there is a unique $g\in G$ with $\theta(g)(x)=y$. If $G$ is a group, $\theta$ is a heap action of $G$ on $X$, $\cdot$ is a group action, and $\theta(g)(x)=g\cdot P(x)$ for each $x\in X$, then the heap action $\theta$ is a heap torsor if and only if the group action $\cdot$ is a torsor.

**One sorted heap torsor**

A one-sorted heap torsor is an algebra $(X,L,\Omega,\mho)$ where $L,\Omega,\mho:X^{3}\rightarrow X$ are ternary operations such that $(X,L)$ is a heap and where the following identities are satisfied:

1. $\Omega(x,y,z)=L(x,\Omega(r,s,y),\Omega(r,s,z))$, and
2. $\Omega(x,y,\mho(y,x,z))=\mho(x,y,\Omega(y,x,z))=z$.

The three notions of a heap torsor, a one-sorted heap torsor, and a heap with permutation coset are dual to one another. Have any other these notions been studied before? Are there any non-trivial theorems about heap torsors in general?

This question is motivated by cryptography since various block cipher round functions including the AES block cipher are heap torsors.

Comment: By the way, $L(L(p,q,r),s,t)=L(p,q,L(r,s,t))$ only together with 2. implies 1.

Comment: Also, probably a more natural (classically but probably not constructively equivalent) notion of action of a heap $G$ is a pair of objects $X$, $Y$ and a map $\theta:G\to\operatorname{Iso}(X,Y)$ with $\theta([i,j,k])=\theta(i)\theta(j)^{-1}\theta(k)$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Perhaps, we should call an action $\theta:G\rightarrow\text{Sym}(X)$ a heap endo-action if we wanted to distinguish this from a more general notion of a heap action (unless you can think of better terminology).

Comment: I think that unlike the general action, what you call endoaction can be factored through the action of the group associated to the heap. The latter is a group $\operatorname{group}(G)$ together with an universal "enrichment" $G\times G\to\operatorname{group}(G)$